# Create report Like static list which can not be selected

Tags: odoo

I want to create report which look like static list this list can not be select and delete.

This type of report is already present in stock(warehouse) but i don't know how i made like static

Screenshot warehouse --> Inventory analysis
[image]

Comment: just look into the code. it's done per database VIEWS. as you've mentioned, stock module has some examples. just look into addons/stock/report/report_stock.py and its view xml report_stock_view.xml. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may try one of the following approaches:

1. Base your report on a PostgreSQL view (as @CZoellner) suggested
2. Create access rules preventing this view to be edited
3. In the xml definition of your view, try the following attributes available with OpenERP 7:

   ```
   <tree create="false" delete="false">
       <...your fields go here...>
   </tree>
   ```